# Efficient way of drawing lines along existing paths in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Let's assume I have two intersecting paths. Now I want to draw another one that will follow parts of them like on the illustration:

[image]

I made this through absurdly inefficient way of just adding anchors at the intersection, cutting them and stitching together which is fine for one line out of two segments but obviously becomes unfeasible for more complicated designs. I'm obviously missing something stupidly simple here so, please, help me out.

Comment: I honestly don't know how you'd do it any differently than adding anchors, splitting, then joining - at least if you want them to remain strokes. I suppose you *could* use shape builder, but that'll only make the "adding anchors" step unnecessary.

Comment: If this is for something like a larger more complex illustration, and not just this very simplified case, I'd look at using the shape builder tool.  What is it you are actually drawing? I think we need to know the bigger picture here.

Comment: @BillyKerr I want to use it for drawing maps. For example I want to be able to draw a border along a river and then start tracing along another country's border. Shape builder, if I understand correctly, doesn't mesh well with unclosed splines.

Comment: Shape Builder is fine with open paths. (It's Pathfinder that doesn't like open paths). The problem is Shape Builder isn't *really* going to save much time. it'll make removing a portion of overlapping paths easier. So, Shape Builder would replace the "add anchors and delete" aspects. But there'd still be the need to "select and join anchors", which I can't think of any alternative for. In short, using Shape Builder would probably save maybe 1 to 3 clicks per segment, but that's it. Sounds to me like it's merely a labor intensive project.

Comment: Now, if you *don't* need strokes to remain strokes. Expand strokes and Shape Builder could save considerable time. But then you have *Shapes* and not stroked paths. Biggest issue is there's no way to join path segments without selecting the anchors. The join shortcut can work to *close* a path without selecting anchors - But for separate path segments then selecting the anchors is the only way.

Comment: @Scott Thank you! I guess the best way is to just start up building shapes in a GIS app, export it to illustrator and just then style everything. Not terribly easy but seems to still be faster.